# selecting percentage of time on/off for groupings by id

Tags: sql

I'm looking to summarize some information into a kind of report, and the crux of it is similar to the following problem. I'm looking for the approach in any sql-like language.

consider a schema containing the following:

```
id - int, on - bool, time - datetime
```

This table is basically a log that specifies when a thing of id changes state between 'on' and 'off'.

What I want is a table with the percentage of time 'on' for each id seen. So a result might look like this

```
id, percent 'on'
1, 50
2, 45
3, 67
```

I would expect the overall time to be

```
now - (time first seen in the log)
```

Programatically, I understand how to do this. For each id, I just want to add up all of the segments of time for which the item was 'on' and express this as a percentage of the total time. I'm not quite seeing how to do this in sql however

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, along with an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` and some date/time arithmetic (which varies by database).

In pseudo-code this looks like:

```
select id,
       sum(csae when status = on then coalesce(next_datetime, current_datetime) - datetime) end) / (current_datetime - min(datetime))
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Date/time functions vary by database, so this is just to give an idea of what to do.